# bootstrapping with 10 million replicates - not enough memory

Tags: r, memory, parallel-processing, statistics-bootstrap

I would like to calculate 10 million bootstrap replicates in R, but my machine does not have enough memory as-is (128 GB).

Right now, I have been doing this using `boot` over multiple cores:

```
boot_data <- boot(data=data, statistic=correlation_fn, R=10^7, 
                  parallel="multicore", ncpus=10)
```

Even before any child processes even start calculating (by monitoring with `htop`, the calculation runs out of memory:

> Error in mcfork() :
>
> unable to fork, possible reason: Cannot allocate memory
>
> Calls: cor_boot_wrap -> boot ->  -> lapply -> FUN -> mcfork
>
> Execution halted
>
> Warning message:
>
> system call failed: Cannot allocate memory

Is there a another way to do this say with memory-mapping (perhaps with `bigmemory` or `ff`)? I realize that this issue can easily be solved by using another machine with more memory, but this is not an option for me.

In the end, I use `boot.ci(boot_data, type="bca")` to calculate confidence intervals, so whatever intermediate method should be compatible with this.

Comment: What kind of analysis are you doing that you actually need 10 million samples?

Comment: It might be possible to make this work, but without a reproducible example there is not much we can do to help you. However, you should first test this without parallelization and try with smaller increasing numbers of n to extrapolate memory demand.

Comment: Good idea, I will work on a reproducible analysis and revise the question.

Answer (score 0):

Can you create a file, or set of files, with the indices that represent the selection for the bootstrap.  You might also write the object itself that would result from each of the bootstraps.  Then your processing would be to read in each file and perform your analysis.  The problem is probably caused by trying to create everything in memory at once.

How about running 1000 bootstraps at a time and then consolidating the results?